# How to group boolean conditions in EL

Tags: jsp, jsf, boolean, el

I'm having trouble evaluating a pair of boolean expressions within a JSF using EL.

Here's my snippet:

```
<a4j:commandButton id="addbtn" value="Add School(s)"
  action="#{somebean.someaction}"                       
  disabled="#{not studentRecords.isValid and not studentRecords.schoolSelected}">
</a4j:commandButton>
```

isValid and schoolSelected are returning boolean result either true or false. But when I'm connection these two with 'and' operator it does not work.

I tried putting

```
!studentRecords.isValid and !studentRecords.schoolSelected
```

But that doesn't also work.

Comment: what is the way to highlight the question in yellow colored box? we can see your question is highlighted. how?

Comment: @AmitG I don's see any yellow colored box are you referring to the code block?

Comment: if **schoolSelected** is a boolean variable, is **isValid** also a boolean variable ? looks like it is a getter method, you should use both of them as **variable**

Comment: @MMRUser it appears to be highlighted in the question's list, doesn't appears after clicking the question. Anyways leave it. Might be this is my login setting because of that I am able to see some question in yellow colored box.

Comment: @AmitG i think you favorited one of these tags of question. Thats why question is highlighted in list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EL expressions will automatically determine the correct managed bean property as long as the setters and getters were written correctly.

### Non-Boolean Managed Bean Property

**Managed Bean:**

```
private Long studentRecordNumber;

public Long getStudentRecordNumber() {
  return this.studentRecordNumber;
}

public void setStudentRecordNumber(Long studentRecordNumber) {
  this.studentRecordNumber = studentRecordNumber;
}
```

**JSF Markup**

```
rednered="#{studentRecords.studentRecordNumber ne null}"
```

### Boolean Managed Bean Property

**Managed Bean:**

```
private boolean valid;

public boolean isValid() {
  return this.valid;
}

public void setValid(boolean valid) {
  this.valid = valid;
}
```

**JSF Markup**

```
rendered="#{not studentRecords.valid and not studentRecords.schoolSelected}"
```

EL expressions however can also be used to directly evaluate the returned result of a Boolean method, however method parentheses must be used.

```
rendered="#{studentRecords.canStudentEnrollToday()}"
```

Comment: Tried these but non of them are working. When I used the bean method directly it gives me a property not found error.